# Stop user from running malicious python code in online compilers

Tags: python, django, security, exec, linux-security-module

I am developing an online compiler wherein user can run python code.My requirement is to run that python code on server side with exec. So I researched on how can I completely eliminate some user running malicious python code and most of the sites suggested this -

1. built-ins disabled
2. Ptrace and chroot jail
3. Sandboxing/VM

But if I store a list of blacklisted commands e.g - ["exec","os","subprocess"] and check the string code for presence of any blacklisted commands and discard it on client side as well as server side then doesn't it solve the problem?

Comment: Years ago there was a try to create such a restricted environment from within Python. It failed because of Python's flexibility (only older users may remember the "rexec" and "bastion" modules). Only way which could be safe is to restrict the process on OS level or maybe to use a VM.

Comment: First, blacklists are always wrong.  Second, `__class__` and `__subclasses__` let you do a *lot*.